# Web.config transform to change value

Tags: web-config

I'm working on a project where I need to include web.config transofrm to change a value depending if it's in the production environment or test environment.

Lets say for example that I want the value **testItem** to be in my test environment  and the value **prodItem** to be in my production environment.

This is how I did it so far.

web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key ="ELeg" value ="testItem"/>
</appSettings>
```

Web.Prod.config:

```
  <configuration>
    <appSettings>
      <add key ="prodItem"/>
    </appSettings>
  </configuration>
```

As you can see the code is similar but the only difference is that I changed the value in the web.Prod.config.

How do I use the web.config transform to correctly change the value in the production environment?